# Кто знает как получить API от Yandex Maps, без указания сайта?

Tags: javascript

Хотелось бы протестировать эти карты локально. Однако требует сайт, а нужно чтобы для себя. Может кто то знает api от карт наподобие Яндекса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На локальном сервере можно использовать любой валидный ключ.

Можно создать ключ с доменом `http://127.0.0.1`

Comment: Спасибо, правильно ли я понял, что в ссылку url сайта для Яндекса мне можно скинуть этот домен? Они просто автоматиком проверяют.

Comment: @Success да, все так